# Using a customer's Zoho client id, but why am i seeing my person zoho account details?

Tags: zoho

I am using Zoho's .Net API to access some email information such as emails and folders.
During development i've been using my personal zoho account (i created a zoho app under client console).

However, now that i've switched over to my customer's configurations (client id & client secret). But still, after requesting for authorization, the account details are still my own!

I assumed the account details would be of my customer's. And therefore, the email and folders details that I request via the API are all related to my account.

Am i misunderstanding how the Zoho API is supposed to work? Or is what im observing what is expected?